# Exception handling vaadin

Tags: java, vaadin7

I have login button that calls a login function

```
if (button == loginbutton) {
    try {
        login();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // I am adding a window compnent here that will display the exception with the message
    }
}
```

Now my login function:

```
private void login() throws Exception {
    accessInterface.signIn(m_username.getValue(), m_password.getValue());
    m_loginListener.loginSuccessful();  
}
```

now it goes to signin function:

```
public boolean signIn(String p_username, String p_password) throws Exception {
    try {
        m_user = UserAuthentication.authenticate(p_username, p_password, 
                ServiceSettings.getInstance().getAuthenticationServiceLocation());


    } catch (Exception e) {
        m_logger.error("CATCH",e);
        throw e;
    }
    // Setting the current user
    CurrentUser.set(m_user); 
    return true;
}
```

now it goes to authenticate method of the service:

```
public static uInterface authenticate(String p_username, String p_password, String p_Location) throws Exception {
    // here it is authenticating user

}
```

Now, the problem is that it is not showing the error or exception in that window component. What should i do? I want to catch my exception in that window component vaadin

Windows Code

It takes ui object, windows Heading, Message and then details of exception on click of details button

```
ExceptionDetails.showMessage(getUI(), 
    "Error in signing in", 
    "ExceptionInformation", 
    e.getLocalizedMessage(), 
    new ActionListenerDetail() {

        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

        @Override
        public void onClickDetails() {
            m_username.focus();
            m_loginButton.setEnabled(true);
        }
    }
);
```

Comment: Try to remove try-catch block from signIn() method. If exception in occur in signIn() then it will be propagate to originial method.

Comment: no i have tried that but still its not catching the exception in window

Comment: Can you post the window's code?

Comment: please see the windows code

Comment: At what point in your code does the exception occur?

Comment: Also, have you tried using `getWindow().showNotification()` to show the message? I've never seen this `ExceptionDetails` function, more info on `showNotification` here: https://vaadin.com/blog/-/blogs/user-notifications-with-vaadin

Comment: see exception details is a common class for showing exception information, i have created it using window component which take some parameters to show exception info and exception comes at login button if i enter wrong username or password but there comes a exclamation mark having that exception and it does show that exception or error in window

Comment: Have you added window component to UI class by calling soething like this AppUI.getCurrent().getWindows().add(window);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The SetErrorHandler in vaadin does the trick to catch this Error